# Trouble connecting with FTP

Tags: ftp

I have a client site they host with GoDaddy. Recently, GoDaddy moved them to a different server due to a security issue with another one of the sites hosted on the same server.

Since the move (2 weeks ago), I have had great difficulty connecting to their server via FTP. Initially, the problem was my hosts file, which had been updated in order to test the new server. Once that problem was corrected, I was able to connect and disconnect freely, for about a day.

Since then, I've had intermittent success connecting. Couldn't connect at all yesterday. kept a connection for about an hour today.

The client admins are having no problem with their FTP access. I have no cPanel access, they do. They can't recreate the problem on their end and I can't get it to work more than 3% of the time.

I have checked my credentials dozens of times at this point. I'm using FTP, passive mode. But I have tried both. I've succeeded and failed with the IP and the domain addresses.

I'm out of ideas. This isn't an issue I've had in decades.

If anyone has any ideas of things to try or settings specific to GoDaddy that should be checked, please let me know.

Comment: I can confirm there has been a problem with FTP access on some of their servers. I suggest opening up a ticket with them via their support (support by phone is usually the quickest, otherwise by email). If you find the problem's been resolved, then please update the question, or provide an answer if you've figured out a solution.

Comment: Will call support and report back when resolved.

Comment: Great. Mine had the same issue (from the U.S.), where I either couldn't connect, or connections were quickly dropped. That resolved after a call to an account rep and there's been no problems since. Might be from a firewall/security issue they need to fix.

Comment: Please update this post with specific details of the failure.  What error messages does your FTP client have?  Also, can you use SFTP (not FTP over SSL). SFTP will use port 22 and avoid some passive/active FTP conflicts with firewalls.

Comment: I haven't updated as it still hasn't been resolved. GoDaddy couldn't find an issue and put it back on me. This is what I get out of the log -- Status: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error: Connection timed out
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...

Comment: @DuffyDolan That's the same issue I've seen. Be sure to ask to speak to the hosting department directly, and request the support ticket to be _escalated_. It's likely that the firewall for your server is set to refuse connections coming from the same client IP within X minutes, and FTP clients usually disconnect and try to reconnect after inactivity, thus triggering that.

Comment: @DuffyDolan NP. You can try to increase the re-connection time and number of tries in your FTP client, but once the IP rule in their firewall is triggered, you'll likely have to wait for that period to expire (might be a few minutes). In the meantime, you can use their File Manager under your Hosting Control Panel page to upload files - just keep your browser open to that page while you're working (it's more clicks, but the upload speed should be good and you'll avoid the connection issues).

Comment: I have tried increasing the re-connection time. It makes no difference. A big part of the problem I have is that I am not the account holder with GoDaddy; my client is and they are not going to give me CP access (I asked). This status is also interfering with productive communication with GoDaddy. And I keep hoping that it really is on my end so I can fix it. What a stupid mess.

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy has 24/7 phone support and if the issue is on there side, they likely can help resolve it.
However I'm unsure of your operating system so this will be general advice.

Try: Clearing your DNS Cache, resetting your FTP password and verify server IP

Try using one of the following in the username field, substituting the appropriate variables Username@Domain.com or UserName@IP

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/96/uploading-files-to-your-website-ftp

Comment: If this fails and if you are familiar with deciphering network traffic, you may be able to use WireShark to capture failures and figure out exactly what is going on. I suspect that will give you the answer and a place to start. I am sure if it is not a configuration issue, then it must be a network issue.